# Python assignment as function input?

Tags: python

Why is it sometimes you can give an assignment as an input into a function?

```
> import threading
> 
> def func(a):
>     a = 0
>     print("thread function")
>     return
> 
> if __name__ =='__main__':
> 
>     t = threading.Thread(**target=func**)
>     t.start()
```

How come we can give **target=f** as an  input, in a normal function I am not able to do this? Why is it sometimes the inputs are assignments?

Comment: That's not an assignment, it's a *keyword parameter*.

Comment: `def f(a,b,c):   pass` and    `f(c=42,a=9,b=99)` - works. What is your problem?